# How can I count the number of vowels and consonants in a string using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to study Haskell, and I'm completely at lost. This exercise requires me to count the amout of vowels and consonants in a string, and print both numbers.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
--Here I take the string and will 
--return a tuple with both values
countVC::[Char]->(Int, Int)
--I call an aux function where I pass the string 
--and two values, which I will use to increment
--according to the amount of vowels or consonants 
countVC = countVCAux txt 0 0

countVCAux::[Char]->Int->Int->(Int, Int)
--If the string is empty I try to return the tuple with (0, 0)
countVCAux [] con vow  = (con, vow)
--If not I take the head and compare with the consonants
countVCAux (c:r) con vow
    --If it's a vowel I pass the rest of the list, the consonant and increment the vowel count
    |c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u' = countVCAux r con (vow + 1)
    --Else I do the same, but increment the consonant count
    |otherwise = countVCAux r (con + 1) vow
```

However it doesn't work. What is the problem with this code?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? There are type errors. First of all, you have to fix them.

Comment: Already did a fix suggested by Chad Gilbert and updated the original post. I now get an error "Undefined variable 'txt'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your `countVC` definition currently does not take a `[Char]` parameter as its signature implies. Change it to this:

```haskell
countVC txt = countVCAux txt 0 0
```

The first `countVCAux` pattern isn't quite right either. `txt` should probably be omitted in favor of the empty string `[]`, and you need to add `con` and `vow` parameters:

```haskell
countVCAux [] con vow  = (con, vow)
```

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the first countVCAux pattern. However I don't understand how am I supposed to change the countVC definition, since the code in your post already matches the same line of code in my original post. I now get an error "Undefined variable 'txt'".

Comment: Woops! I just fixed my answer. The first example now includes `txt` as a parameter

Comment: Thank you so much Chad! Working great now! :D